# Build a .ko file using a .o file

Tags: c, makefile, linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module

I know that we can make a .ko file using a source .c file with a subsequent makefile given below. Now, I want to create a same kind of .ko file without exposing the source. So I planned to do it using the .o object file. But I'm not hitting the right path, How do I modify the Makefile according to this requirement?

```
obj-m += somesource.o

all:
    make -C $(KERNEL_SRC) M=$(PWD) modules 


clean:
    make -C $(KERNEL_SRC) M=$(PWD) clean
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, one **cannot** build kernel module from **object files created on other machine**. The only exception is *shipped files*, which may contain code, but cannot provide any symbol (variables or functions).

I guess this is a protection against using functions and/or types, defined in one kernel, in different kernel with incompatible function signature or type layout.

If you don't want to expose the source, build *complete* kernel module on your machine and distribute it.

Comment: thanks for the response, there is no other way I can do it without this? For instance, the .c file gets converted to .o file and the .mod.o file is generated from .mod.c file from  the kernel source. The two object files are dynamically linked. 

If I'm not wrong, can we hack this procedure in between and proceed with these two available object files?

Comment: It is very possibly that you may hack this procedure, but I don't know how. Kernel build process and its Makefiles structure are complex actually.